# ANSI equivalent of IS NULL

Tags: sql, coalesce, isnull, ansi-sql

I am trying to find the ANSI way to write the T-SQL 'IS NULL'. (corrected, was 'IN NULL')
Some posts on the internet say you can use coalesce to make it work like 'IS NULL'

The reason I like to do this: portable code. And the query must return the rows that are `NULL`.

So far I created this:

```
SELECT empid,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       country,
       coalesce(region,'unknown') AS regions ,
       city
FROM HR.Employees
```

The result set looks like:

```
empid   firstname           lastname       country  regions city
1           Sara            Davis           USA     WA      Seattle
2           Don             Funk            USA     WA      Tacoma
3           Judy            Lew             USA     WA      Kirkland 
4           Yael            Peled           USA     WA      Redmond
5           Sven            Buck            UK      unknown London
6           Paul            Suurs           UK      unknown London
7           Russell         King            UK      unknown London
8           Maria           Cameron         USA     WA      Seattle
9           Zoya            Dolgopyatova    UK      unknown London
```

I identified the rows that are `NULL`, but how do I filter them out of this set?

Comment: If there is a better way to filter, do tell.

Comment: So you want your query to return all of the above rows except those with a `regions` value of `unknown`?

Comment: Are you trying to say `unknown` is `NULL`?

Comment: Do you wish to see the NULL rows only?

Comment: @chihwahli . . . I assume the first line of your question is about `IS NULL` not `IN NULL` (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: @ Daniel: wanted it to work, return either... it works now. thanks for the effort.

Comment: @njk : I was trying to filter out the rows with NULLS. Did not know how to continue. But I know now. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `IS NULL` and `COALESCE` are ANSI standard and available in almost all reasonable databases.  The construct that you want, I think, is:

```
where region IS NULL
```

This is standard syntax.

To have `COALESCE` work like `IS NULL` requires a value that you know is not in the data:

```
where coalesce(region, '<null>') <> '<null>'
```

However, you would need different values for dates and numbers.

Comment: I read a few pages on the web, telling me that IS NOT was T-SQL only. But that was wrong. Thanks for the correction. I rewrote my original code, just to try out coalesce:

Comment: SELECT empid,firstname,lastname,country,coalesce(region,'unknown') AS regions ,city
FROM HR.Employees
where coalesce(region, '<null>') = '<null>'
or region = N'WA'

Returns the rows with NULL now. Will archive it and use 'IS NULL' in the future then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing `IS NULL` (a predicate that checks to see if a value is null) and the T-SQL specific function `ISNULL(value, replace)` (no space and parameters after it), which is similar, but not identical to `COALESCE`.

Please see [SQL - Difference between COALESCE and ISNULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828641/sql-difference-between-coalesce-and-isnull) for details on how `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` differ for T-SQL.

Minor differences like what type is returned and what happens when all the arguments are null aside, `ISNULL` is a function that returns the first argument if it is not null, or the second argument if it is.  `COALESCE` returns the first non-null argument (it can take more than two).

As a result, each of these might be used to solve your problem in different ways and with slightly different results.

Answer (score 3):

`IS NULL` is valid ANSI SQL-92, is called the null predicate.

```
<null predicate> ::= <row value constructor> IS [ NOT ] NULL
```

See [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), paragraph 8.6.

So `WHERE`column name`IS NULL` is perfectly valid.

The bit where ANSI SQL treats NULL values different from T-SQL is when you write `WHERE` column name `= NULL` or `WHERE` column name `<> NULL`. See [SET ANSI NULLS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out it's ANSI, read the wrong pages and thought wrongly.