# SQL - Difference between COALESCE and ISNULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the practical differences between COALESCE() and ISNULL(,'')?

When avoiding NULL values in SQL concatenations, which one is the best to be used?

Thanks!

Comment: `coalesce` is defined by the SQL standard and will work on nearly all DBMS. `isnull()` only works with Microsoft products.

Comment: `ISNULL` takes two parameters, `COALESCE` can take `n` parameters, it depends on the requirement and version of SQL Server as to which is preferred

Comment: MySQL also has isnull.

Comment: I found the ISNULL vs COALESCE question before asking this one. But I asked the practical differences when concatenating columns (performance, best practices, code behaviour etc), that's why I created a new question. Sorry if it was a duplicated question.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> Comparing COALESCE and ISNULL
>
> The ISNULL function and the COALESCE expression have a similar purpose but can behave differently.
>
> 1. Because ISNULL is a function, it is evaluated only once. As described above,
>    the input values for the COALESCE expression can be evaluated multiple
>    times.
> 2. Data type determination of the resulting expression is
>    different. ISNULL uses the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE
>    follows the CASE expression rules and returns the data type of value
>    with the highest precedence.
> 3. The NULLability of the result expression is different for ISNULL and COALESCE. The
>    ISNULL return value is always considered NOT NULLable (assuming the return value is a
>    non-nullable one) whereas COALESCE with non-null parameters is
>    considered to be NULL. So the expressions ISNULL(NULL, 1) and
>    COALESCE(NULL, 1) although equivalent have different nullability
>    values. This makes a difference if you are using these expressions in
>    computed columns, creating key constraints or making the return value
>    of a scalar UDF deterministic so that it can be indexed as shown in
>    the following example.
>
>    ```
>    USE tempdb; 
>    GO
>
>    -- This statement fails because the PRIMARY KEY cannot accept NULL values
>    -- and the nullability of the COALESCE expression for col2 
>    -- evaluates to NULL. 
>
>    CREATE TABLE #Demo  (  col1 integer NULL,  col2 AS COALESCE(col1, 0) PRIMARY KEY,  col3 AS ISNULL(col1, 0)  ); 
>
>    -- This statement succeeds because the nullability of the 
>    -- ISNULL function evaluates AS NOT NULL.
>
>    CREATE TABLE #Demo  (  col1 integer NULL,  col2 AS COALESCE(col1, 0), col3 AS ISNULL(col1, 0) PRIMARY KEY  );
>    ```
>
> Validations for ISNULL and
> COALESCE are also different. For example, a NULL value for ISNULL is
> converted to int whereas for COALESCE, you must provide a data type.
> ISNULL takes only 2 parameters whereas COALESCE takes a variable
> number of parameters.

Source: [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: +1. What's more, `COALESCE` is just a shortcut for a `CASE` expression, meaning that the optimizer rewrites it to use `CASE` instead

Comment: @paxdiablo Books OnLine, the official SQL Server documentation. Sorry, not sure it is still called it, but it used to be.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that makes substantially more sense than my attempts :-)

Comment: An [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26224588/538763) of type handling for (2):

Answer (score 20):

The main difference is, that `COALESCE` is ANSI-Standard, so you will also find it in other RDBMSs, the other difference is you can give a whole list of values to be checked to `COALESCE` whereas to `ISNULL` you can only pass one.

Answer (score 13):

Because `ISNULL` is a function, it is evaluated only once. As described above, the input values for the `COALESCE` expression can be evaluated multiple times.
`COALESCE` basically translates to `CASE` expression and `ISNULL` is a built-in implemented in the database engine.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: _"`ISNULL` is faster than `COALESCE`."_ [citation needed]. In which cases? Why?

Answer (score 10):

`COALESCE()` can have multiple inputs and it will evaluate in order until one of them is not null such as `COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, 'N/A')`. It's recommended to use this by MS instead of `ISNULL()`

`ISNULL()` can only have one input, however it's been shown to be slightly faster than COALESCE.