# make null value as X sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have problem.., i want to display the null value as 'X' 
i has been using the case statement but still failed, 
i already using Isnull and failed too.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @X AS NVARCHAR(MAX)



SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(code)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM edrsDB..tbl_users where area='west' ) AS status

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT date, '+ @ColumnName +' 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_status
WHERE DatePart(MM, [Date]) = 3
 And DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) = 2017
Union
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday
WHERE DatePart(MM, [Date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) = 2017
Union
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date 
FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend
WHERE DatePart(MM, [Date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) = 2017
And date IS NOT NULL
 ) AS x 
 PIVOT
 (
max(status)
FOR userid IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
) AS PVTTable'
 EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

this is ouput.. , i want null to be display as 'X'

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iXNi.png)

Comment: `coalesce(column, 'X')` will return X if column is null.

Comment: how to insert this  ... '+ @ColumnName +'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL`

```
ISNULL(<some_column/some_stuff>, 'X')
```

`'X'` would be the value displayed instead of the first parameter if first parameter result is null

Comment: how to insert '+ @ColumnName +'  and set x ?

what i done is like this

Comment: ISNULL('+@Columnname+' , ''X'') AS '+@Columnname+'

Comment: ''X'' ,, i use single quote

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL function in SQL Server :

```
SELECT ISNULL(Your_column,'X')
```

Comment: done do like that ,, but i dont know why error ...,

this is what id done

Comment: ISNULL('+@Columnname +' , ''X'' ) As '+@Columnname+'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isnull()` or `coalesce()` in sql server.

```
select isnull(col,'X')
```

or

```
select coalesce(col,'X')
```

The main difference between the two is that `coalesce()` can support more than 2 parameters, and it selects the first one that is not `null`. More differences between the two are [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828687/2333499)

```
select coalesce(col,col2,'X')
```

`coalesce()` is also standard ANSI sql, so you will find it in most RDBMS. `isnull()` is specific to sql server.

Reference:

- [**`isnull()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [**`coalesce()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: how to implement to my code..? i has been try but nothing happen