# If else condition in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have serial number, test name and few other columns, i want to write a condition if `TESTNAME is null` for a particular serial number then set the `TESTNAME` to blank else perform inner join

```
SELECT 
    (A.PTNUMBER + '-' +A.SL_NO) AS ENUMBER, 
    D.ENGINEER AS REQ, D.DATETIME as "DATE",
    (select Value 
     from DROPDOWN 
     where B.TEST_NAME=CONVERT(VARCHAR,DropdownID)) TESTNAME, 
    TABLE_NAME AS TABLETD 
FROM INSPECTION D 
INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON D.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID) 
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID) 
INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON C.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID)
```

Comment: check out the case keyword (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) show us what you have so far as well. We're not mind readers :)

Comment: Next time, start with the query. It will prevent answers which fail to capture the scope of your question or properly address it. Hypothetical questions are not [Minimal, Complete, or Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To improve your answers, [review this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include test data [as explained here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) with expected results. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by *set testname to blank* but if you meant to be using a `SELECT` query then you can do like

```
select *,
case when TESTNAME is null and serial_number = some_value then '' end as TESTNAME
from mytable
```

Comment: when  B.TEST_NAME is null or B.TEST_NAME ='0' then ''
  instead of setting TEST_NAME  blank, i want to set another column 'VALUES' which is in table D to BLANK since
  in table D i have a column(dropdownID) that is mapped to column(test_name) in table B. 
Hence , my objective is when TEST_NAME(in table b) is 0 or null,   then set Values(in table D)to blank.

I tried case when TEST.TEST_NAME IS NULL OR TEST.TEST_NAME = '0' then D.Values ='' but its says incorrect syntax. Please help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: SELECT (A.PTNUMBER + '-' + A.SL_NO) AS ENUMBER, D.ENGINEER AS REQ,     D.DATETIME as "DATE",  case   when SerialNo = xxx and B.TEST_NAME is null or B.TEST_NAME ='0' then ''  else (select Value from DROPDOWN where B.TEST_NAME = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DropdownID))   end AS VALUES, TABLE_NAME AS TABLETD 
  FROM INSPECTION D  INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON A.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID)   INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID) 
  INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON C.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID)
  INNER JOIN TABLED D ON D.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID);

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a `case` expression and `coalesce()` along with your join to choose the value you want to return.

```
select serial_number, ... 
  ,case when coalesce(testname,'') <> ''
          then t2.testname 
        else coalesce(testname,'') end
from t
  inner join t2
    on ...
```

---

You can use `isnull()` or `coalesce()` in sql server to return a different value to replace `null`.

```
select isnull(testname,'')
```

or

```
select coalesce(testname,'')
```

The main difference between the two is that `coalesce()` can support more than 2 parameters, and it selects the first one that is not `null`. More differences between the two are [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828687/2333499)

```
select coalesce(testname,testname2,'')
```

`coalesce()` is also standard ANSI sql, so you will find it in most RDBMS. `isnull()` is specific to sql server.

Reference:

- [**`isnull()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [**`coalesce()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Below is my query, how can I set TESTNAME to blank if its NULL and perform join condition and populate values SELECT (A.PTNUMBER + '-' +A.SL_NO) AS ENUMBER, D.ENGINEER AS REQ, 
D.DATETIME as "DATE",(select Value from DROPDOWN where B.TEST_NAME=CONVERT(VARCHAR,DropdownID)) TESTNAME,
TABLE_NAME AS TABLETD
FROM INSPECTION D 
INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON D.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID)
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID)
INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON C.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.EN_ID)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (A.PTNUMBER + '-' + A.SL_NO) AS ENUMBER, 
       D.ENGINEER AS REQ, 
       D.DATETIME as "DATE",
       case
        when SerialNo = xxx and TESTNAME is null then ''
        else (select Value from DROPDOWN where B.TEST_NAME = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DropdownID))
       end AS TESTNAME, 
       TABLE_NAME AS TABLETD 
  FROM INSPECTION D
  INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON D.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID) 
  INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID) 
  INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON C.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID);
```

Comment: I want to test if a TEST_NAME is null and 0 then set to blank but since TEST_NAME  is a varchar, my SQL statement doesn't set null to blank, can you please help me with this?

Comment: This is the condition                                                                  TEST.TEST_NAME IS NULL OR TEST.TEST_NAME = '0' then ''

Comment: I don't understand what you need, sorry. SELECT (A.PTNUMBER + '-' + A.SL_NO) AS ENUMBER, 
       D.ENGINEER AS REQ, 
       D.DATETIME as "DATE",
       case
        when SerialNo = xxx and TESTNAME is null then ''
        else (select cast(Value as varchar) from DROPDOWN where B.TEST_NAME = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DropdownID))
       end AS TESTNAME, 
       TABLE_NAME AS TABLETD 
  FROM INSPECTION D
  INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON D.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID) 
  INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID) 
  INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON C.ENGID = CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.EN_ID);