# How to join on two fields where one could be null

Tags: sql-server

This query may seem basic, but i'm at a fairly basic level.

So here is my data - **Sorry about the formatting, i've tried following the help but the table formatting is obviously not working for me (Can someone please advise?)**:

Table 1

```
ID |Country
---| ------- 
1  | UK
1  | IE 
1  | US   
2  | UK 
2  | FR
```

Table 2

```
ID |Country
---| ------- 
1  | UK
1  | IE 
2  | UK
```

The result i want is this

```
Table 1-----  | ----Table 2

ID |Country   |-----ID |Country
---| -------  |--------|--------
1  | UK       | 1      | UK
1  | IE       | 1      | IE
1  | US       | 1      | NULL
2  | UK       | 2      | UK
2  | FR       | 2      | NULL
```

But more specifically i want to identify the NULL's so that i get this result

```
Table 1-----  | ----Table 2

ID |Country   |-----ID |Country
---| -------  |--------|--------
1  | US       | 1      | NULL
2  | FR       | 2      | NULL
```

The code i have used so far is:

```
select *
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.country = t2.country
where t1.id is not null
and t2.country is null
```

Comment: you can use CTRL+K for table formatting

Comment: what is t2.upc ?

Comment: Thanks Paul. @ GuidoG - Sorry that was a typo, i've updated it now

Comment: `WHERE t1.Country <> t2.Country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you just need to use `isnull()` or `coalesce()`.

```
select 
    t1.id
  , t1.country
  , t2_Id = isnull(t2.id,t1.id)
  , t2_country = t2.country 
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.country = t2.country
where t1.id is not null
  --and t2.country is null
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/XCNH52338

returns:

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| id | country | t2_Id | t2_country |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 | UK      |     1 | UK         |
|  1 | IE      |     1 | IE         |
|  1 | US      |     1 | NULL       |
|  2 | UK      |     2 | UK         |
|  2 | FR      |     2 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

with the additional filter of `t2.country is null`

returns:

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| id | country | t2_Id | t2_country |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 | US      |     1 | NULL       |
|  2 | FR      |     2 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

---

The main difference between the two is that `coalesce()` can support more than 2 parameters, and it selects the first one that is not `null`. More differences between the two are [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828687/2333499)

`coalesce()` is standard ANSI sql, so it is available in most RDBMS. `isnull()` is specific to sql server.

Reference:

- [**`isnull()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [**`coalesce()`** - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)
- [`coalesce` vs `isnull` - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t1.id, t1.country, isnull(t2.id, t1.id) AS T2_ID, t2.country
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.upc and t1.country = t2.country
```

if you want to only show the ones where you have nulls in t2, you can add

```
where t2.id is null
```

But if you want to show all the records, just leave it without the WHERE condition

Comment: Hi Agapwlesu,  i've tried to translate your code to my tables but i keep getting a error stating "The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).". Can you help please?     select st.upc,
  st.RELEASE_STATUS,
  st.OWNING_COUNTRY,
  st.GRS_GRANDFATHER,
  st.GRCS_DATA_RECEIVED,
  st.LEGAL_RIGHT_COUNTRY,
   iif(isnull(rs.id), st.id, rs.id) AS T2_ID, iif(isnull(rs.id), "NULL", rs.country) AS T2_Country
from dbo.[UATinGRS rows] st
left outer join dbo.UATBatchOneResult rs on st.upc = rs.upc and st.LEGAL_RIGHT_COUNTRY = rs.LEGAL_RIGHT_COUNTRY

Comment: That's not how you use [**`isnull()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) in sql server.

Comment: It's been a while since I used sqlserver, but I was hoping you got the idea (need to test for null t2.id and substitute from t1.id or the word "NULL" for the country) and translated.  I will edit to fix it.