# Using SELECT subquery in a CASE statement and handling NULLS

Tags: sql, case, common-table-expression

I have 2 SQL tables one holding stock information then a style table which details how the stock is used. For some jobs the information is contained with a print file so the value in the stock table would be BIN, if not it would contain a template name which would cause a query to a `Styles` table which then shows how the stock is used. There a 10 positions that a stock could be applied but the template table wouldn't have records for where a stock couldn't be used (on the back of a simplex job for example).

I have a stored procedure which works to provide the detail based on whether the logic value is BIN or not but for the records in the style table that have no value I get NULL back which I need to suppress but just putting `ISNULL` around the column name in the subquery isn't having any effect. Am I just missing something as I'd rather not nest in another `CASE` statement to check if the query would produce `NULL`

```
WITH STYLES AS 
(
    SELECT 
        @JOBNAME AS JobName, Logic AS StyleName 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[CON_Tbl_511_DigitalStocks]
    WHERE  
        JOBNAME = @JOBNAME
)
SELECT TOP 1 
    [Logic], 
    [S1F], [S1B], [S2F], [S2B], 
    [S3F], [S3B], [S4F], [S4B],
    [S5F], [S5B],
    CASE 
        WHEN b.stylename = 'BIN' 
            THEN --checks if there is a style for this job
                CASE 
                    WHEN S1F = '' THEN '' 
                    ELSE '1' 
                END -- if a stock code is specified then return the bin name ("1")
            ELSE (SELECT PAGE 
                  FROM [dbo].[CON_Tbl_512_DigitalLogic] 
                  WHERE STYLENAME = B.StyleName 
                    AND STOCKREF = 'S1F') 
    END AS S1F_LOGIC,    -- If a style is used return the style instruction for this bin and side 
    CASE 
        WHEN b.stylename = 'BIN' -- repeat this for all bins/sides
            THEN 
                CASE WHEN S1B = '' THEN ''
                ELSE '1' 
            END 
            ELSE (SELECT PAGE 
                  FROM [dbo].[CON_Tbl_512_DigitalLogic] 
                  WHERE STYLENAME = B.StyleName AND STOCKREF = 'S1B') 
    END AS S1B_LOGIC,
    CASE WHEN b.stylename = 'BIN' THEN 
            CASE WHEN S2F = '' THEN ''
                ELSE '2' END 
            ELSE  (SELECT PAGE FROM [dbo].[CON_Tbl_512_DigitalLogic] WHERE STYLENAME = B.StyleName AND STOCKREF = 'S2F') END AS S2F_LOGIC -- this one returns NULL as there is no instruction required for "2SF"
FROM 
    [CON_Tbl_511_DigitalStocks] A 
JOIN 
    STYLES B ON A.JOBNAME = B.JOBNAME
WHERE 
    A.JobName = @JobName
```

This code works fine until the last one as there is no value in the stockref column that says 'S2F' but putting `SELECT ISNULL(PAGE, '')` still returns NULL

Comment: Use something like `isnull((select ....), '') as ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this query is not finding any records:

```
SELECT PAGE FROM [dbo].[CON_Tbl_512_DigitalLogic] WHERE STYLENAME = B.StyleName AND STOCKREF = 'S2F'
```

and you want it to return something, you can change it to:

```sql
SELECT coalesce(min(PAGE),'') FROM [dbo].[CON_Tbl_512_DigitalLogic] WHERE STYLENAME = B.StyleName AND STOCKREF = 'S2F'
```

This will return the minimum value (`min`) of the found records, which will return NULL when noting found. The `coalesce` will turn this NULL into the empty string: `''`

P.S.: see also [SQL - Difference between COALESCE and ISNULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828641/sql-difference-between-coalesce-and-isnull)